# Volume when rotated about the line $y=-1$

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Find the volume when the region enclosed by $y=x^2$, $y=4$ is revolved around the line $y=-1$

My teacher has given the following answer:

$$\text{D.} \quad 4\pi \int_0^4(y+1)\sqrt{y} \, dy$$

I assume she has done this through the method of shells, due to the the $4\pi$ outside the integral, but I don't know how to come up with this. Can anyone help?
All I know is that $\sqrt y$ is when $y$ is a function of $x$, and the $y+1$ is the radius I guess? But where does the $4\pi$ come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that the radius of the shell is $r = y + 1$ (the height of the blue line minus the height of the red line). The height of the shell is given by

$$ h = \sqrt y - (-\sqrt y) = 2 \sqrt y.$$

Using cylindrical shells, the desired quantity is

$$
\int_0^4 2\pi r h \ dy = \int_0^42\pi(y+1)(2\sqrt y) \ dy = 4 \pi \int_0^4(y+1) \sqrt y \ dy \approx 228.
$$

See the plot below:

[image]

Comment: Could you explain how to get the intergal? What steps you took?

Comment: See my edit and plot. Note that the height is the "top" of the green curve minus the "bottom" of the green curve. The height from the $y$-axis to the green curve is clearly $\sqrt y$. By symmetry, the height of the shell is $2 \sqrt y$.

Comment: Ok I think I get it. Could you also help me with the region bounded by y=sinx,x=0,x=pi,y=0 revolved about the y-axis. my answer was pi^2/2, yet the correct answer is 2pi^2. What is wrong with my integral -----> [picture](http://i.snag.gy/SzsCg.jpg)

Comment: Please make a new question for that, I would be glad to help. Try to show your steps so we can identify where you went wrong.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out! Thanks for your help with this question

Comment: No problem. Best of luck!